# Как можно реализовать такой блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно представляю, что нужно использовать псевдоэлементы и абсолютное позиционирование, для того, чтобы расставить картинки в нужное место.
Сам блок реализован через "flexbox"
Возможно, есть какой либо другой способ, потому что, при этом варианте картинки у меня выходят за пределы контейнера

Comment: С какими именно трудностями вы столкнулись?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Разместить по бокам стикеры (ананас и сердце), если сам футер реализован через "Flex"

Answer (score 1):

Да скорее всего будет уместным - через ::before и ::after и через абсолютное позиционирование поставить как тебе будет нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен ваш, вопрос. Но если речь про то, как можно организовать быстро и с заделом под адаптив footer вашего сайта, то я рекомендую вам сделать это с помощью CSS свойства `display: flex`. У CSS Tricks есть отличная [статья на эту тему](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: да, я не совсем точно описала проблему: он как раз и реализован через "Flex", и исходя из этого и возникла проблема размещения стикеров в углах(верхнем и нижнем)